# Display product cost in front end

Tags: magento

I'm trying to get the Cost of a product to display in the front end list view. I have a store with just downloadable products, and for setting up prices for downloads, you have to set the product cost to $0.00 and then you add the price for each downloadable in the links section.

So in the backend i have set up the price i want to show up front under the 'cost' section so it doesnt get included in the calculations, but i would like to show that cost price in the front end list view.

Any idea how to accomplish this

thanks

Comment: I don't understand, why can't you put the price in the "Price" field?

Comment: The reason why, is that with downloadable products. If you have the price set in the price field, then set the price of your downloads in the links area.  When viewing that product, the base price was starting at 1.99 for the product, and then each download added was an additional 1.99. With made 1 download file be 3.98.

For my case , i had a music track and it could be downloaded as a midi file, mp3 file with vocals, mp3 file without vocals. I needed the price to start at $0.00 and then each selection of a download would add 1.99, not start at 1.99 and add for each product.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You'll need to change the attribute configuration.
Go to Catalog -> Attributes -> Manage Attributes select the attribute Cost and change the option "Used in Product Listing" to "Yes".
After you save you can call you attribute value into your template using: $_product->getCost()