# Magento, just can't select a custom attribute

Tags: php, magento

Hi I'm trying to select a custom attribute in my script.

Here is my code

```
$collection = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection()

->addAttributeToSelect('jan')

->addAttributeToSelect('name')

->addAttributeToSelect('upc')

->addAttributeToSelect('ean')

->addAttributeToSelect('price')

->addAttributeToSelect('cost_price')

->addAttributeToSelect('subtitle')

->addAttributeToSelect('url_key')

->addAttributeToSelect('brand')

->addAttributeToFilter('sku', array('eq' => '30000387'));
```

Then I do a foreach loop to go through the $collection as $item

I am able to pull all these values using $item->getData('insert atttribute code here')

Except for the cost_price no matter what I do I can't seem to pull cost_price I have tried

```
$item->getData('cost_price')
$item->getCostPrice()
```

I have tried reindexing and removing the cache just in case, to no avail.  The value is definitely filled in the product I am selecting.

Help much appreciated.

Comment: Take a look on database table eav_attribute, and look for this one cost_price, check if the code are the same and the attribute group is 4 if its all right. You have a big problem. ;)

Comment: Well it exists in the database entity_type_id is 4.  So I guess I have a big problem.  Maybe I will resort to direct sql queries.

Comment: Try geting the product id and load it, if the attribute don't show i sugest u remove it and put again

Comment: Hmm, loading the product by id and then retrieving cost_price works.  Why not through a normal collection though?!!!!

Comment: I remeber something, try Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection()
->addAttributeToSelect('*'); this should bring all attributes

Comment: Did you try http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5914973/display-product-cost-in-front-end ?

Comment: Have you try with just ->addAttributeToSelect('price') ?

Comment: @Guerra, I had already tried a wildcard star which did not bring load the attribute.

Comment: Bixi Yes I have tried with just 'price' and it loads fine, all my other custom attributes also load.

Comment: R.S Thank you, when I set cost_price to 'be used in product listing:yes' it loads, the odd thing is that my other custom attributes load fine without this setting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you always want the cost_price attribute to be loaded (without every time having to call load on the product), it might be a better solution to make it always load by either:

- going to the backend, Catalog -> Manage Attributes -> select your attribute, and selecting "Yes" for "Visible on Product View Page on Front-end" and "Used in Product Listing"
- adding the eav attribute in the catalog config.xml:

  ```
  <product>
      <collection>
          <attributes>
              <name/>
              <url_key/>
              <price/>
              <special_price/>
              .....
              <cost_price/>
          </attributes>
      </collection>
  </product>
  ```

(don't edit core files though, create your own module)

Comment: I selected 'yes' for 'product used in listing'.  Now the attribute loads fine.  What is strange is that my other custom attributes load fine without me having to set this setting.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
 <?php echo $_product->getResource()->getAttribute('cost_price')->getFrontend()->getValue($_product); ?>
```